# I need the output with 0.5 difference in for loop

Tags: php

I have this for loop:

```php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
   echo "The number is: $x <br>"; 
}
```

For the above for loop the output will be:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

But I need the difference by 0.5, like this:

```
0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5 .......
```

Comment: change it to `for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x+= 0.5) {   echo "The number is: $x <br>"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with 0.5 for incrementing

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x+= 0.5 ) {   echo "The number is: $x <br>"; }
```